# How to add Widgets to a PyQt5 already using a Qt designer layout "Spoiler" I have figured how to close and open another window in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, widget, pyside6

I was able to create a window using Qt Designer, but am unable to dynamically add a QPlainTextEdit widget to it. I have tried in all places, but always the program exits without an error. Here is the code which includes a simple way to close and open a form. I looked everywhere, but there were no answers. This way works perfectly without any errors just remove the

```
self.b = QPlainTextEdit(self)
self.b.insertPlainText("You can write text here.\n")
self.b.move(10,10)
self.b.resize(400,200)
```

portion of the code and create another Window using the same layout as this

```
from mimetypes import init
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QFileDialog,QPlainTextEdit
from appsui import Ui_QTAppsWindow
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QFileDialog

global numberofapps
numberofapps = 1

def initloadApps(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('django.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("select * from Project")

    rows = c.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        global numberofapps
        numberofapps = row[4]

    conn.close()
    
class AppsMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_QTAppsWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppsMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        initloadApps(self)
        print(str(numberofapps))
        # Add text field
        self.b = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.b.insertPlainText("You can write text here.\n")
        self.b.move(10,10)
        self.b.resize(400,200)
        self.btnNext.clicked.connect(self.btnNext_Clicked)
        self.btnPrevious.clicked.connect(self.btnPrevious_Clicked)

    def btnPrevious_Clicked(self):
         AppsMainWindow.close(self)
         if 'main' in sys.modules:
            del sys.modules["main"]
         from main import MainWindow

    def btnNext_Clicked(self):
        pass
 
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   
try:
    window=AppsMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Django Creator (Apps)")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication([])
```

Everything is done in Python, they say it is greater than C#, prove it. Because I made the same thing in C#.Net without any problems.

If you remove the **self** from

`self.b = QPlainTextEdit(self)`

You get this error

**QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget**

And exits, and I looked everywhere for the error and didn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: "they say it is greater than C#, prove it." The power of a language cannot do anything about one's inexperience or bad code. If you got those errors, it's because you're doing things *wrong*, and Python has absolutely nothing to do with it. For instance: 1. the try/except block is at the wrong indentation level; 2. if you get that error, it's a Qt error, not a Python one, and it means that you did something else wrong, but, 3. you cannot know because *you* didn't properly catch the exception (which would be a conceptual problem on *any* language); 4. you shouldn't use globals.

Comment: That said, it's not clear to what "self" you're referring in that line, but removing any of that wouldn't cause that error. And widgets should always be added to a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (which in the case of QMainWindow means the layout of the *central widget*), not added "freely" and then setting their geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you just have to add QPlainTextEdit to the

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QFileDialog

line and create a normal variable name for

```
    # Add text field
    AppsTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self)
    AppsTextEdit.insertPlainText("You can write text here.\n")
    AppsTextEdit.move(10,100)
    AppsTextEdit.resize(400,200)
```

And voilà it works Nothing like trial and error "Perseverance is a virtue"

Comment: If you properly used the exception (by storing and showing it, eg: `except Exception as err:` `print(err)`) you would've seen the error in the debug output. Actually, you'd have also seen the problem if you didn't use the try/except block at all. Besides, this demonstrates that the issue had absolutely **nothing** to do with the "greatness" (or lack) of the language.